# Are these two 2008 & 2009 Dojo books hopelessly out-of-date/worthless?

Tags: dojo

About 5 yrs ago I bought 'Practical Dojo Projects' and 'The Concise Guide to Dojo' (Wrox.)  But these 2008 & 2009 books don't even mention which version they are written for.  I now have a project I want to do in Dojo. Are these books of any use today or will they just confuse me because of the major changes in Dojo ? Should I just wait (maybe 2 years or more ???) for Dojo 2.0 to be released ?

Answer (score 1):

What is written in these books is still valid but outdated.
Thanks to a very good backward compatibility from Dojo, almost all what you will read in the books can still be used.
However, Dojo syntax has changed and even if the legacy syntax (the one in the books) is still valid, they now encourage you to use the AMD syntax.

[this page](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/releasenotes/migration-17.html) will help you "converting" the syntax in the book into the more modern syntax. Appart the syntax change, almost all what you learn in the books is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Most programming books are outdated especially if they were writing ~8 years ago. Your best bet is to read their docs, recent tutorials, or any articles about the framework. Also make sure the community around the tool is still active and that you can get support if you get stock anywhere in the middle of dev your new app.